# Dialog Box Message for user on Windows (Python)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, dialog, window

I would like to display Warning Dialog Box for current logon User in Windows when I run python .exe from C:\Program Files\MyFolder as SYSTEM.

Actually there is an application which is running with SYSTEM privileges and it runs this .exe script but User is logged in with his privileges.

I am using this code:

```
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import messagebox
win = Tk()  
win.geometry("200x200")  
messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Proces was killed")  
win.mainloop()
```

but the Warning Window doesn't display for User.
I guess it is showing in SYSTEM content but not in User.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If the posted code is *all the code* in the script, then it should fail to run because you haven't imported the required modules.

Comment: Sorry for this, of course I do it: 

`from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import messagebox`

Comment: If you run an exe as a service, services cannot create windows.